# Compile a program in a "compatibility mode"

Tags: compiling, compatibility

I need to use a program called [SPMRoot](http://www.dfn.if.usp.br/~suaide/pelletron/spmroot.html). It works great on Ubuntu 12.04, but somehow it can't compile without errors in ubuntu 14/04 due some libraries dependencies or anything like that.
Is there a way I can compile it using a "compatibility mode" or any other workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider running it in a precise chroot.

There are some instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot) (although they're somewhat out of date).  Hopefully you can adapt them for your needs.

Good luck

EDIT: The instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) look a bit more up to date and you may find them easier to follow.

Comment: this could produce problems on shared librarys.

Comment: Umm, I don't see how?  Care to expand?

Comment: I am sorry I did misunderstand you. I thought, that you want him to compile on 12.04 and then use the compiled binary on 12.04. Your answer will _hopefully_ work +1

Comment: hmmm this look interesting. I will try them later. Thanks Sir

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded `root_v6.04.06.source.tar.gz`, installed `libxpm-dev`.

(complete build dep list is on https://root.cern.ch/build-prerequisites)

And it compiles on 15.04.

Comment: that is the solution I have been waiting for (+1)